# Autolayout Constraints Breaking on Widths Equally

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am applying constraints using IB on few views just for learning purposes. The constraint "Width Equally" is applied on the red and blue view. But as soon as I apply it shows a yellow line for the autolayout constraint. Both views have width 258. Here is an image: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. To fix it, you must add additional constraints until the red and blue views are fully constrained.

When a view has no constraints on it whatsoever, interface builder assumes you just want it literally positioned where it is on the canvas currently. However, as soon as a view has at least one constraint, auto layout takes over. In this screenshot, auto layout is complaining because you have only specified the width of the red and blue views – and only to each other, in that they must be equal. You'll need to make sure that both the red and the blue views have both an X and Y location and a width and height defined.

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome! I did not knew that the IB is just asking for more constraints. This makes sense. I added few more constraints and now I am getting somewhere :) Cool! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. :) If you click the white arrow in the red circle next to the words "View Controller Scene" in your picture, IB will tell you exactly what it is upset about.